# 1993 Model Craftsman (917.257560) dies when blades are engaged

Tags: lawnmower, craftsman

So this mower is only 5 years younger than I am... I was having problems with it last weekend when I was trying to get it out. Charged the battery, checked the carb and checked the starter. Everything looked fine. I bypassed the seat safety cause I thought that was the culprit. Put everything back together and it started and purred like a kitten. It was to late to start mowing so I put her up. Yesterday I was going to mow so I started it up and went to engage the blades and it died. I think there is a safety switch of some sort at the end of the engage/disengage lever under the dash. That is a whole other problem cause I can't figure out how to take the dash off... please advise.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be a better fit on [gardening.se](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I see other lawn mower questions....

Comment: That's on you but you may likely get better answers from people that regularly work on mowers but what would I know by looking at their 37 questions surrounding [mowers](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn-mower).

Comment: Thanks for the help!!!.. Reason I didn't post there is because the whole first page was asking about plants. Unless anyone else objects I'll leave my small engine problem in the mechanics section. If you don't want to offer any help please leave.

Comment: Ah ok..  sorry for trying to help you find the best way to answer your question.  That's my bad.

Comment: Indeed. Have a great day.

Comment: When it dies, does it seem like its having a hard time moving the blades?  Does the engine stop turning _very_ quickly like it's in a bind or does it just sputter to a stop like the ignition is cut out (like turning off the key or tripping a safety switch)?

Comment: I don't think it gets to moving the blades. I can move them by hand if that's what you're asking. When I move the lever it starts to die, then I can release the lever and it will start back.

Comment: I agree it is off topic, this SE is for "cars, trucks, and motorcycles." As Mr. Vader said, you would probably have better luck on the gardening site. PS  we're only trying to help, the sass isn't necessary.

Comment: I've also seen several power equipment questions over on [DIY.SE](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions).  I don't hand out on Gardening, so I'm not sure if one is better than the other.

Comment: Please advise on how to close since this is causing a problem. Thank you for your feedback. I'll head over to the plant people.

Comment: This is not a question for Gardening IMO.    This is a small engine site as well.  This should remain open.

Comment: Agree with @DucatiKiller - This question is an exact fit for this SE ... I don't have much more than a clue about who is trying to close it, but would suggest it stay open. Not saying there isn't crossover here, but we've had several questions on power mowers.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I agreed with the vote to close because the engine "purred like a kitten", so it was having to do with lawn mower auxiliary functions, rather than motor vehicle.

Answer (score 1):

Clogged carberator.
Basically the main jet is clogged.  Engine runs fine until you put a load on it.

Remove carburetor.  Carefully disassemble it (save the gaskets).  Using a can of carb cleaner, blow out all the passages especially the main one (usually a tube sticking in the throat of the carb - small bend in the cleaning straw of carb cleaner is usually good enough to reach it). Reassemble etc.

I had one there was a piece of green corrosion in the main jet.  It was hard like a piece of sand but it had the patena of oxidized copper (copper green).  Not sure what it was but it was on an engine that was run dry and stored over the winter.

In the future, use fuel stabilizer in ALL your small engines.  you never know when you are going to pack it for the last time unless you consciously winterize the motors.

If you find serious rust behind the mixture screw, consider buying a new carb.  The Chinese ones on Amazon seem to work OK - make sure you buy one with correct levers and attachments.